# How to find all upstream DG nodes with maya python api?

Tags: python, maya

I can use

```
hypershade -listUpstreamNodes
```

to get them, but this command is not available in maya batch mode.
i guess i should use  [MItDependencyGraph](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_it_dependency_graph.html) ? can someone give me a short example ? thanks !

ps: i want to find all anim curves on anim controls( they may be in anim layers). another place i can use this is find all shading nodes associated with a given mesh. i don't want to use listConnections or connectionInfo multiple times and write a long function to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in vanilla maya python

```
 import maya.cmds as cmds
 cmds.ls(*cmds.listHistory (mynode), type = 'animCurve' )
```

Should do the same thing.  In both cases you'll also have to look for things like driven keys that will show up in the results.

Comment: just tried, listHistory doesn't return anim curves connected to the controller.( the curves are created by setting keys on the controller)

Comment: If the controller has a shape (ie, mesh or spline) you have to query the transform attributes directly: listHistory (mynode + ".t")

Comment: thanks ! sorry but have another problem, how can i use this to get all animCurves for an object in an animLayer ? currently it returns all curves (including curves in other layers and in base layer) if i query curves on the object.

Comment: I'd try a two step answer: make a python set out of the results of this, and a python set of the contents of the animlayer (AnimLayer -anc) and then intersect the sets.

Answer (score 2):

found an awesome example somewhere ....
and a great reference : [introduction-to-the-maya-api](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/maya-api-programming/introduction-to-the-maya-api/)

```
# Python code
import maya.OpenMaya as om

animCurves = []
# Create a MSelectionList with our selected items:
selList = om.MSelectionList()
om.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(selList)

# Create a selection list iterator for what we picked:
mItSelectionList = om.MItSelectionList(selList)
while not mItSelectionList.isDone():
    mObject = om.MObject()  # The current object
    mItSelectionList.getDependNode(mObject)
    # Create a dependency graph iterator for our current object:
    mItDependencyGraph = om.MItDependencyGraph(mObject,
                                               om.MItDependencyGraph.kUpstream,
                                               om.MItDependencyGraph.kPlugLevel)
    while not mItDependencyGraph.isDone():
        currentItem = mItDependencyGraph.currentItem()
        dependNodeFunc = om.MFnDependencyNode(currentItem)
        # See if the current item is an animCurve:
        if currentItem.hasFn(om.MFn.kAnimCurve):
            name = dependNodeFunc.name()
            animCurves.append(name)
        mItDependencyGraph.next()
    mItSelectionList.next()

# See what we found:
for ac in sorted(animCurves):
    print ac
```

modified :

```
def getAllDGNodes(inNode,direction,nodeMfnType):
    '''
    direction : om.MItDependencyGraph.kUpstream
    nodeMfnType : om.MFn.kAnimCurve
    '''    
    import maya.OpenMaya as om

    nodes = []
    # Create a MSelectionList with our selected items:
    selList = om.MSelectionList()
    selList.add(inNode)
    mObject = om.MObject()  # The current object
    selList.getDependNode( 0, mObject )

    # Create a dependency graph iterator for our current object:
    mItDependencyGraph = om.MItDependencyGraph(mObject,direction,om.MItDependencyGraph.kPlugLevel)
    while not mItDependencyGraph.isDone():
        currentItem = mItDependencyGraph.currentItem()
        dependNodeFunc = om.MFnDependencyNode(currentItem)
        # See if the current item is an animCurve:
        if currentItem.hasFn(nodeMfnType):
            name = dependNodeFunc.name()
            nodes.append(name)
        mItDependencyGraph.next()

    # See what we found:
    for n in sorted(nodes):
        print n

    return nodes
```