# How to get data from an upstream node in maya?

Tags: maya

I have a maya node `myNode`, which creates a `shadeNode`, which `inMesh` attribute is connected to `shapeNode.outMesh` and has an attribute `distance`.

```
myNode.outMesh -> shapeNode.inMesh
myNode.distance = 10
```

Then i have a command, which works on the shape node, but requires the distance argument, which it does by iterating over the `inMesh` connections:

```cpp
MPlugArray meshConnections;
MPlug inMeshPlug = depNodeFn.findPlug("inMesh"); 
inMeshPlug.connectedTo(meshConnections, true, false); // in connections

bool node_found = false;
for(uint i = 0; i < numConnections; i++) {
    MPlug remotePlug = meshConnections[i];
    myNode = remotePlug.node();
    if(MFnDependencyNode(myNode ).typeName() == "myNode") {
        node_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
MFnDependencyNode myDepNode(myNode);
MPlug distancePlug = myDepNode.findPlug("distance");
```

Now i get a problem, when applying another node (of another type) to `myShape`, because the dependency graph now looks like this:

```
myNode.outMesh -> myOtherNode.inMesh
                  myOtherNode.outMesh -> shapeNode.inMesh
myNode.distance = 10
```

I tried to remove the check for `typeName() == "myNode"`, because i understood the documentation like there should be recursion to the parent node, when the next node return `Mstatus::kInvalidParameter` for the unknown MPlug, but i cannot reach the `distance` plug without implementing further graph traversion.

What is the correct way to reliably find an attribute of a parent node, even when some other nodes were added in between?

The command itself should use the distance Plug to either connect to `myNode` or to some plug which gets the value recursively. If possible i do not want to change `myOtherNode` to have a distance plug and correspondig connections for forwarding the data.

Comment: Re you sure you want to debug your code for all eternity?

Comment: I am rather new to maya and inherited a big pile of maya code, which doesn't follow the usual maya structures. Currently i do my best to get it working and try to adapt it as i work with it to more maya like structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [an answer (python code)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738405/893159) to the question how to get all nodes in the graph. My code to find the node in the `MPxCommand` now looks like this:

```cpp
MPlugArray meshConnections;
MPlug inMeshPlug = depNodeFn.findPlug("inMesh"); 
MItDependencyGraph depGraphIt(inMeshPlug, MFn::kInvalid, MItDependencyGraph::Direction::kUpstream);
bool offset_mesh_node_found = false;
while(!depGraphIt.isDone()) {
    myNode = depGraphIt.currentItem();
    if(MFnDependencyNode(myNode).typeName() == "myNode") {
        offset_mesh_node_found = true;
        break;
    }
    depGraphIt.next();
}
```

The `MItDependencyGraph` can traverse the graph in upstream or downstream direction either starting from an object or a plug. Here i just search for the first instance of `myNode`, as I assume there will only be one in my use case. It then connects the distance `MPlug` in the graph, which still works when more mesh transforms are inserted.

The [MItDependencyGraph](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_it_dependency_graph_html) object allows to filter for node ids, but only the numeric node ids not node names. I probably add a filter later, when I have [unique maya ids](http://mayaid.autodesk.io/) assigned in all plugins.

Answer (score 2):

The usual Maya workflow would be to make the node operate in isolation -- it should not require any knowledge of the graph structure which surrounds it, it just reacts to changes in inputs and emits new data from its outputs.   The node needs to work properly if a user manually unhooks the inputs and then manually reconnects them to other objects -- you can't know, for example, that some tool won't insert a deformer upstream of your node changing the graph layout that was there when the node was first created.

You also don't want to pass data around outside the dag graph -- if the data needs to be updated you'll want to pass it as a connection.  Otherwise you won't be able to reproduce the scene from the graph alone.  You want to make sure that the graph can only ever produce an unambiguous result.

When you do have to do DAG manipulations  -- like setting up a network of connectiosn -- put them into an `MPXCommand` or a mel/python script.

Comment: Hmm, i will look into it, why it wasn't done in the ``MPxCommand``, which is creating the node. Probably it can be moved there. I am currently refactoring a 4 plugin pipeline, which works when you do the right clicks in an exact order, so i have a lot of such things to change.

Comment: Typically you can do it in the node creator function -- but you should do the nodes in a way that works as well as possible if the node network is edited by your users. so make all node->node dependencies explicit

Comment: My problem here: I have like inMesh, NodeA (with plug), Mesh1. Then I transform Mesh1 and get inMesh, NodeA, NodeB, Mesh1. Now i want to Add NodeC, which transforms Mesh1 and depends on NodeA. I could try to place it on the selection of Mesh1 or NodeA, in both cases i have to trace the other one in some way. And i do not now if there is only NodeB or if NodeB2 was added in between. As you said, other code or the user may have changed the connections freely. Having the user select NodeA and Mesh1 adds too much complexity in handling for the user.

Comment: Back at the code. The real problem here (currently solved with my answer below) is, that i have a transform node NodeA, which gets Mesh1 as input and gives Mesh2 as output. NodeB gets Mesh2 (possibly after some transforms) and Mesh1 (with the same transforms as before NodeA) as input. The command creating the network must not be too complex to the user not interested in the underlying network. As Mesh1 is actually an array and NodeA/B are working on an array of input meshes, i now build the network when the command is run with Mesh2 (or NodeB) as selection.

Comment: FWIW it's usually easier to do the dag manipulation -- which isn't performance sensitive -- in python with maya.cmds or mel.  It's simpler to update it in response to artist workflow ideas that way.  `cmds.listHistory` and `cmds.listConnections` do different versions of the graph traversal in `MItDependencyGraph`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help in understandig more "how maya works". I accepted my self-answer as it contains working code and is the current solution we will use at the moment, but i appreciate your help.